# Parse a string like a CSV file with seek, rewind, position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, file-io

My application accepts an uploaded file from the user and parses it, making use of seek and rewind methods quite heavily to parse blocks from the file (lines can begin with 'start' or 'end' to enclose a section of data, etc).

A new requirement allows the user to upload encrypted files. I've implemented decryption of the content of the file and return the content string to the existing method. I can parse the string as a CSV but lose the file controls.

Storing an unencrypted version of the file is not an option for business reasons.

I'm using FasterCSV but not averse to using something else if I can keep the seek/rewind behaviour.

Current code:

```
FasterCSV.open(path, 'rb') do |csv| # Can I open a string as if it were a file?
  unless csv.eof? # Catch empty files
    # Read, store position, seek, rewind all used during parsing
    position = csv.pos
    row = csv.readline 
    csv.seek(pos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and experimentation I've found that it was possible to retain the IO methods by using the `StringIO` class like so:

```
csv = StringIO.new(decrypted_content)
unless csv.nil?
  unless csv.eof? # Catch empty files
    position = csv.pos
    row = csv.readline.chomp.split(',')
    csv.seek(pos)
```

Only change is needing to manually split the line to be able to use it like a csv row, not much extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the CSV gem anymore but if you prefer the seek/rewind behaviour you can roll your own for strings.  Something like this might work for your scenario:

```
array_of_lines=unecrypted_file_string.split('\n')
array_of_lines.each_with_index do |line,index|
    position=index
    row=line
    seek=line[10]
end
```